# Looping start to end timespans overnight

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timespan

hope all is swell!

I was hoping I had cracked this problem but it looks like we have ran into some errors this morning.

This is an asp.net web application, and this section is in c#.  We are dynamically populating drop down lists with a openTime, closeTime, and Interval of 15 mins which are all of type `TimeSpan`.

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0,15,0);

    for (TimeSpan i = openTime; i <= closeTime; i = i.Add(interval))
    {

        string stringTime = i.ToString();
        ddlTime.Items.Add(new ListItem(stringTime, stringTime));
    }
```

This works great if the times are not over lapping midnight.  Ex:

- openTime: 07:00 (7:00 a.m.)
- closeTime: 10:00 (10:00 a.m.)

Will populate as expected:

- 07:00:00
- 07:15:00
- 07:30:00
- 07:45:00
- .
- .
- 10:00:00

Where this fails to work, is when the opening time starts before midnight, and the close time starts after.

- openTime: 11:00 (11:00 a.m.)
- closeTime: 02:00 (2:00 a.m.)

I need to populate

- 11:15:00
- 11:30:00
- 11:45:00
- .
- .
- .
- 2:00:00

But as you could quickly tell, the loop will not run because the openTime is not <= to closeTime in this scenario.

Simply creating another for loop to check if closeTime <= openTime will not give the desired results.
I would get:

- 02:00:00
- 02:15:00
- 02:30:00
- .
- .
- .
- 11:00:00

Could anyone more experienced on the subject provide what logic is required to get this working successfully.

Thanks for your time, Chris.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it would be better to create a `DateTime` for each of start and end, then loop over *that* until you reach the end, taking the `TimeOfDay` for each value:

```
TimeSpan interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

for (DateTime current = openTime; current <= closeTime; current += interval)
{
    string stringTime = current.TimeOfDay.ToString();
    ddlTime.Items.Add(new ListItem(stringTime, stringTime));
}
```

Now if you have an open time of (say) 28th June 2012, 11pm and a close time of 29th June 2012, 2am then it will work fine.

If you get the open/close times as TimeSpans, you could always use:

```
// The dates don't really matter here... we just want a sample start/end
// for an opening period
DateTime open = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) + openTimespan;
DateTime close = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1) + closeTimespan;

if (open > close)
{
    close = close.AddDays(1);
}
```

Of course I'd personally recommend using my own .NET date/time API, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), which has a specific `LocalTime` type, but that's a different matter :)

Comment: Hey Jon, thanks again for your help!  I solved this by adding a day to the close time if the open time was less, that way, my loop always fires, handling the correct time periods.

Comment: @ChrisBuckler: Cool - and I've fixed my sample code which was broken :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a `TimeSpan` for this, if you're concerned about dates as well?

Instead of `TimeSpan.Add(interval)`, use [`DateTime.Add(new TimeSpan(0,0,interval))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx), and modify the rest of your code to work around a `DateTime` object instead of a `TimeSpan` object.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you use TimeSpan where you should use DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of options:

1. Use a `DateTime` structure instead to do your 15 minutes increments. Take the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` to as you data. (this has been suggested by others while I was writing this)
2. Include logic that substract 24h if the `TimeSpan` value exceeds 24h.

One key note about #1 and the suggestions from others is the inveitable time change for **Daylight saving time**. You'd have to verify that your sequence does not have duplicates when we fall back or skips 1h block when we spring forward.

Does this make senses?

Regards.

Comment: I use TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(stringid) to load a time zone info object for the specified timezone id.  I then use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow,tzi) to load a DateTime object.  The tzi obj actually has support for daylight savings time!  Thanks for the DateTime structure tip!